# In clojure, why does assoc require arguments in addition to a map, but dissoc not?

Tags: clojure

In clojure,

```
(assoc {})
```

throws an arity exception, but

```
(dissoc {})
```

does not.  Why?  I would have expected either both of them to throw an exception, or both to make no changes when no keys or values are provided.

**EDIT**: I see a rationale for allowing these forms; it means we can apply assoc or dissoc to a possibly empty list of arguments.  I just don't see why one would be allowed and the other not, and I'm curious as to whether there's a good reason for this that I'm missing.

Comment: `(assoc {})` makes no sense, therefore it is not allowed.

Comment: Note that `(dissoc {})` doesn't either.

Comment: My argument is that either both make sense, or neither make sense; but one is allowed and the other isn't (at least on clojure 1.5.1).  I'm curious as to why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally think the lack of 1-arity assoc is an oversight: whenever a trailing list of parameters is expected (`& stuff`), the function should normally be capable of working with zero parameters in order to make it possible to `apply` it to an empty list.

Clojure has plenty of other functions that work correctly with zero arguments, e.g. `+` and `merge`.

On the other hand, Clojure has other functions that *don't* accept zero trailing parameters, e.g. `conj`.

So the Clojure API is a bit inconsistent in this regard.....

Answer (score 0):

This is not an authoritative answer, but is based on my testing and looking at ClojureDocs:

[dissoc](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/dissoc) 's arity includes your being able to pass in one argument, a map. No key/value is removed from the map, in that case.

```
(def test-map {:account-no 12345678 :lname "Jones" :fnam "Fred"})
(dissoc test-map)
{:account-no 12345678, :lname "Jones", :fnam "Fred"}
```

[assoc](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/assoc) has no similar arity. That is calling assoc requires a map, key, and value.

Now why this was designed this way is a different matter, and if you do not receive an answer with that information -- I hope you do -- then I suggest offering a bounty or go on Clojure's Google Groups and ask that question.

Here is the source.

```
(defn dissoc
  "dissoc[iate]. Returns a new map of the same (hashed/sorted) type,
that does not contain a mapping for key(s)."
  {:added "1.0"
   :static true}
  ([map] map)
  ([map key]
   (. clojure.lang.RT (dissoc map key)))
  ([map key & ks]
   (let [ret (dissoc map key)]
     (if ks
       (recur ret (first ks) (next ks))
       ret))))
```

Comment: I am not adding this to my answer, because it is an educated guess. It appears that the arity of one is for use in partial functions and Thrush operators. That is a (dissoc test-map) might be threaded into a form that eventually contains a key for removal. But, this is an educated guess, and I'm hoping a Clojure knowledgeable person will answer.